# Sympy works in terminal but not in Jupiter notebook or jupyterlab, any advice?

Tags: python, sympy, apple-m1, arm64, apple-silicon

Hardware/Software: 
MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2021 - M1 max (macOS Monterey Version 12.4) and Python 3.9.13.

Have tried:

`pip install sympy` 
`pip install -U sympy`
`conda install sympy`
`conda install -c conda-forge sympy`

In terminal it works fine:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>>
```

But in both jupyter-lab and Jupiter notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from sympy import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy
```

Comment: compare `sys.version_info, sys.executable` in both places? And maybe `platform.processor()` too since it's M1

Comment: `>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` 
`>>> sys.executable
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python'
`>>> platform.processor()
'i386'` Don't know how to interpret this sir?

Comment: pdf2image have worked fine until now, not sure if it's related but any suggestions highly appreciated
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2image'`

Comment: I'm running the same system.  So two things: Are you running this in a conda environment and, if so, are you sure it's been activated? And, if not, I'd highly recommend it. Also, not so much for this but I suggest miniforge for the M1 if you aren't already using it.

Comment: @MoHoushmand We wanted to compare the output, so you'd need two output to compare, I only see one. It would tell us if both places you are trying (python repl) and jupyterlab are even using the same python environment.

Comment: @creanion ah yes maestro, in jupyter-lab it's something else: `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10'` `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`
`'arm'` how can I syncronise the install or install in both 'arm' and 'i386'?

Answer (score 1):

1. Debugging step as proposed by @creanion

   a:
   In terminal:

   ```py
   $python

   >>> sys.version_info


   sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0) 

   >>> sys.executable
   /usr/local/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python

    >>> platform.processor()

    'i386'

    b
    While in jupyter-lab: 

   sys.version_info
    sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

   sys.executable

   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10’

   platform.processor()

   'arm’
   ```
2. Creating virtual environment as suggested by @hrokr
   Install

   ```
   conda create -n pyc39  python=3.9
   ```
3. Install `ipykernel`

   Was not sure if I should have activated `env` in prior to this step, and or everything here was necessary, however the following was globally installed

   ```py
   conda install ipykernel

   python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name pyc39 --display-name "pyc39”

   conda install -n pyc39 nb_conda_kernels

   conda install -n pyc39 ipykernel
   ```
4. Activate env, open jupyter-lab and choose the newly created `pyc39` to verify

   ```py
   conda activate pyc39

   jupyer-lab!

   from sympy import *
   ```